# Record Vim macro after running commands

Tags: vim

In my normal workflow in Vim, I sometimes realize after the fact that I could have recorded a macro after making a bunch of edits to a line. I then record the macro and type out the actions again for another line, before using the macro.

I would like to record all of the actions run on a single line to a macro, after the fact. Is this possible?

I have not tried anything yet, because I do not know if this command exists.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't record something after it happened.